# The same route command that worked on XP fails on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, vpn, routing

I connect to work's VPN on my laptop. In my last laptop (XP), I added a route so that I can RDP into my work laptop from my desktop while the laptop is on VPN. But now, with the new laptop with Windows 7, the same route entry fails and as a result, the moment my laptop is connected to work's VPN, I can no longer access it from my desktop. Here's what used to work on XP:

```
route -p add 192.168.1.2 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.7 metric 1
```

**Laptop** is **192.168.1.7** and **Desktop** is **192.168.1.2**

Please help me figure this out.

Output of Route Print

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 36...........................VPN Secure Connection
 14...xx xx xx xx xx xx ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
 12...xx xx xx xx xx xx ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN
 11...xx xx xx xx xx xx ......Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.7     25
    2.255.255.254  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      10.21.12.94  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      10.21.12.95  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.21.12.104  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.21.12.105  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.21.12.156  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.21.12.157  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      10.79.199.6  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6    276
     10.79.249.67  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      10.100.44.8  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    10.115.68.110  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    10.115.68.112  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    10.134.202.15  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     10.156.34.68  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    139.71.65.141  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    139.71.65.143  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.49.34  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.49.35  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.49.73  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.49.74  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.102  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.103  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.201  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.205  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.49.238  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.52.126  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.52.200  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.171.53.48  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.171.53.101  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.172.3.179  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    148.172.79.88  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.172.124.22  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.172.134.233  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.173.129.25  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.173.129.82  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.173.133.19  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.173.165.105  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.173.250.141  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.173.250.202  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
   148.173.251.64  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  148.173.251.205  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     164.12.33.56  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7     26
      192.168.1.6  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
      192.168.1.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
     192.168.1.15  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
     192.168.1.17  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.79.199.6    276
      224.0.0.252  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  239.255.255.250  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6     21
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.79.199.6    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.7       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: What is the error, and what VPN software and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Aventail 10.5.3 for VPN. There is no error. It adds the route fine but when I try to ping 192.168.1.2 (desktop), it times out.

Comment: Can you [edit] and add the results of `netstat -rn` once you have established a VPN session and added the route?

Comment: The weird thing is, using the above route, creates the permananet one but also adds an entry to the Active Routes with a Metric that's n+25 where n is what I entered in the route command. I didn't see that happen in XP.

Comment: This may well be a result of the VPN software upgrading as much as the OS.  This issue is common to VPNs in general: at the headend, administrators define whether the client should permit access to the local lan, and any other IP address while the VPN is established.  It seems likely they have disabled local lan access, and this just wasn't very effective on XP.  Perhaps ask them?